# sql SELECT in IF EXISTS

Tags: sql, if-statement, select, mariadb-10.3

I'm trying to run this :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT id_commande FROM historique WHERE id_commande = 57 AND device = 70635601)
BEGIN
    SELECT id_commande FROM historique WHERE id_commande = 57 AND device = 70635601
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT (MAX(id_commande)+1) FROM historique
END
```

I hope you can understand what I want to do. My problem is that it always gives me back `Erreur dans la requête (1064): Syntax error near 'BEGIN SELECT 1 END ELSE BEGIN SELECT 2 END' at line 2`.

Thank you for helping me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without `EXISTS` by using `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT id_commande FROM historique WHERE id_commande = 57 AND device = 70635601),
    (SELECT MAX(id_commande) + 1 FROM historique)
  )
```

I assume that the 1st query would return only 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id_commande FROM historique WHERE id_commande = 57 AND device = 70635601) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can LEFT JOIN to a sub-query with values.
Then COALESCE the value or max.

**For example:**

> ```
> create table historique 
> (
>    id int primary key auto_increment,
>    device int,
>    id_commande int
> );
>
> insert into historique 
> (device, id_commande) values
> (70635601, 57), 
> (70635601, 63);
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> SELECT 
> coalesce(
>    max(case 
>        when val.id_commande = hist.id_commande 
>        then hist.id_commande 
>        end),
>    max(hist.id_commande)+1,
>    1
> ) as id_commande
> FROM (
>   select 
>   70635601 as device,
>   57 as id_commande
> ) val
> LEFT JOIN historique hist
> ON hist.device = val.device
> GROUP BY val.device
> ```
>
> ```
> | id_commande |
> | ----------: |
> |          57 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=81afc5d80138eb6aceaa1ea668b12d14)*